# SQL Server : constraint on table insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a constraint on several tables that house incoming data files. The constraint needs to check that the account number in the inbound files is found in the outbound file table.

Can this be done even though the account number is not a primary key in either outbound or inbound tables? Both tables house daily files so the same account will get inserted every day so there are dupes so cant create a primary key.

Comment: Generally speaking, a constraint is relative to a specific table and row. More importantly, a constraint is itself checked when rows are inserted or modified - so this sort of intra-table checking depends on your insertion/modification logic. Sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but you will need to provide more detail to move forward.

Comment: @SMor I bet you haven't seen this from spaghettidba which uses  indexed views to enforce arbitrary cross-tables constraints: [Enforcing Complex Constraints with Indexed Views](https://spaghettidba.com/2011/08/03/enforcing-complex-constraints-with-indexed-views/) I can do a write up for OP if the table definitions are provided

Comment: Come to think of it, I don't think that solution works here as it's a constraint against a **non existence**. But we should be able to get something to work here via a linking table

Comment: [Create Foreign Key Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15): "A foreign key constraint doesn't have to be linked only to a primary key constraint in another table. Foreign keys can also be defined to reference the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table."

Comment: @HABO In this case it's unlikely to be unique as it's just an account number

Comment: Thank you all.. since all my tables all have dupe rows i decided to take another route and i dropped in a few lookup steps in the package dataflows to validate the account numbers on the incoming files.. I havent used looksup in the past however im confident it should solve my problem.. Later on im going to create one accounts table with distinct account listing and set up the PK there and add FK to the other daily files tables..  FK can be non-unique, correct?